# PhpStorm and EasyPhp

Tags: php, phpstorm, easyphp

I just started using StormPhp, 
and i wanted to use EasyPhp, whenever i want to run an application, it asks me to Edit the configuration, and i get an

> error : "PHP interpreter is not installed.Press "Fix" to edit your
>   project configuration".

I tried to configure it my self, i putted :

```
PHP Home : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\apache\bin 
Include path : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\
```

But i still get "PHP Version: Not installed"

[image]

Comment: PHP Home should point to php.exe like C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe

Comment: thank you ... now im getting PHP Startup : Unable to load dynamic library ... :/

Comment: _"Unable to load dynamic library"_ -- you are using some extension that requires DLL that cannot be found in default Windows locations. This has nothing to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: yea .. what can i do to solve it then :/?

Comment: Have you added the folder to your environment variables in windows?

Comment: not really .. i told i just started using it .. and where can i find it??

Comment: 1) Try restarting your computer first - maybe that path was added to PATH variable but not "visible" to OS yet. 2) If still nothing -- try adding path to **PHP** folder with `*.dll` file to PATH system variable

Comment: nope didnt work ... can i just set it when i press like F9 it opens it in google chrome or something like that?

Comment: You can setup PhpStorm to open your file directly in browser. For that: 1) Create (and mark as Default) a deployment entry in "Settings | Deployment"; 2) Now you can use "View | Open in browser..." or similar (the URL (domain name) will be taken from Deployment entry.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create **Run Configuration** for that specific file (Run | Edit Configurations... -- an entry of "PHP Web Application" type) -- then you can use "Run" button to open that file in browser. **Obviously** -- none of these ideas will be able to help you will the actual "unable to load dynamic library" problem. They are rather "workarounds" so you can skip defining PHP interpreter at all.